# Missing boundary in request (Error: content-type missing boundary)

Tags: http, multipartform-data, form-data, boundary

I had this proxy:

```
router.post('/proxy/foo', function (req, res, next) {

  const proxy = http.request({
      method: 'POST',
      port: 4000,
      hostname: 'localhost',
      path: `/files/foo`,
      headers: {
         'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
      }
    },
    function (resp) {
      resp.pipe(res).once('error', next);
    });

  req.pipe(proxy).once('error', next);

});
```

I was sending a POST request to this proxy handler using, the following headers:

```
{ 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------842381361531134328792158',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'postman-token': '1a5daa0b-2643-45bc-accc-3f7f3ced948d',
  'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.1.1',
  accept: '*/*',
  host: 'localhost:3040',
  cookie: 'cdt_app_token=foobar',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'content-length': '176',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
```

Given that, I was getting this error:

> Error: content-type missing boundary

So I changed it so that it the proxy request used the same headers as the original request, which makes sense:

```
   const proxy = http.request({
      method: 'POST',
      port: 4000,
      hostname: 'localhost',
      path: `/files/foo`,
      headers: Object.assign({}, req.headers) // <<<<<<<<<
    },
    function (resp) {
      resp.pipe(res).once('error', next);
    });
```

Now it works, because of this header in particular:

```
'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------842381361531134328792158'
```

So what is that boundary thing?